# Why override method always call from object of subclass?

Tags: java, oop, object, overriding

Can you please clear the concept why override method always call from the instance of a child when it typecast to its parent?
I have written the piece of code to understand the concept.
Is override method only, take place in the subclass?

```
class A {
        int x = 15;
        int marry(int a) {
            System.out.println("pppppp parent marry: " + a);
            return 0;
        }

        void show(int a) {
            System.out.println("pppppp parent show: " + a);
        }
    }

    class B extends A {

        int x = 10;
        void show(int a) {
            System.out.println("pppppp child show: " + a);
        }

        void wedding(int a) {
            System.out.println("pppppp child wedding: " + a);
        }
    }


 private void test() {
        A b = new B(); 
        b.show(10); //pppppp child show: 10
        b.marry(34);//pppppp parent marry: 34
        System.out.println("pppppp b.x: " + b.x);  //pppppp b.x: 15
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        B a = (B)b; 
        a.show(22);  //pppppp child show: 22
        a.wedding(22); //pppppp child wedding: 22
        a.marry(22);//pppppp parent marry: 22
        System.out.println("pppppp a.x: " + a.x); //pppppp a.x: 10
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
```

Comment: *when it typecast to its parent* I don't see any casts to the parent type in this example.  The only cast you do casts to the child type: `B a = (B)b;`

Comment: Because Java uses [dynamic binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding).

Comment: @0x54... I have done up typecast then down typecast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's the point of polymorphism. Methods are called by the type of the **instance**, **not** by the type of the **reference** to the instance of a class. Also, be sure to read about [dynamic dispatch](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-method-dispatch-runtime-polymorphism-java/) in java. Also, your case is perfectly fits [this article's](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-binding-and-dynamic-binding) content.